# Не выполняется setInterval (задание из книги JS для детей)

Tags: setinterval

setInterval(nissan.moveRight, 250); при выполнении этой строки в консоли выбивает сообщение Cannot read property 'css' of undefined at Car.moveRight. Если же, выполнять вручную nissan.moveRight() - все работает. Почему так выполняется?

```
var Car = function(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    };
    Car.prototype.draw = function() {
        var carHtml = '<img src="http://nostarch.com/images/car.png">';
        this.carElement = $(carHtml);
        this.carElement.css({
            position: "absolute",
            left: this.x,
            top: this.y
        });
        $("body").append(this.carElement);
    };
    var tesla = new Car(300, 0);
    var nissan = new Car(200, 100);
    tesla.draw();
    nissan.draw();
    Car.prototype.moveRight = function() {
        this.x += 5;
        this.carElement.css({
            left: this.x,
            top: this.y
        });
    };
  setInterval(nissan.moveRight, 250);
```

Comment: выведите в консоль this  и carElement  и посмотрите что они представляют из себя.

Answer (score 1):

Происходит "потеря контекста", при указании ссылки на функцию нужно его явно привязать

```
setInterval(nissan.moveRight.bind(nissan), 250);
```

```js
var Car = function(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    };
    Car.prototype.draw = function() {
        var carHtml = '<img src="http://nostarch.com/images/car.png">';
        this.carElement = $(carHtml);
        this.carElement.css({
            position: "absolute",
            left: this.x,
            top: this.y
        });
        $("body").append(this.carElement);
    };
    var tesla = new Car(300, 0);
    var nissan = new Car(200, 100);
    tesla.draw();
    nissan.draw();
    Car.prototype.moveRight = function() {
        this.x += 5;
        this.carElement.css({
            left: this.x,
            top: this.y
        });
    };
  setInterval(nissan.moveRight.bind(nissan), 250);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: лучше было за дубликат проголосовать

Answer (score 1):

Лучше так.
Есть более новый вариант.
Новые удобный синтаксис.

```
class Car {
    constructor(x ,y){ 
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    draw = () => {

        var carHtml = document.createElement('img');
        carHtml.src = 'http://nostarch.com/images/car.png'; // '<img src="http://nostarch.com/images/car.png">';
        this.carElement = carHtml;
        this.carElement.style.position = 'absolute';
        this.carElement.style.left = `${this.x}px`;
        this.carElement.style.right = `${this.y}px`;
        this.carElement.style.transition = '.5s';



        document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].append(this.carElement);
    };
    moveRight = () => {
        console.log(this);
        this.x += 50;
        this.carElement.style.left = `${this.x}px`;
        this.carElement.style.right = `${this.y}px`;
    }

}

window.onload = () => {
    var tesla = new Car(300, 0);
    var nissan = new Car(200, 100);
    nissan.draw();
    setInterval(nissan.moveRight, 250);
}
```

Comment: такой синтаксис не работает. Хотя в хроме не падает, но в спецификации пока нет возможности свойства создавать таким образом

Comment: странно у меня все работает

Comment: В каких браузерах пробовал?

Comment: Поправил ответ к

Comment: хроме   и все пока

Comment: Похоже пока это только в хроме и работает, например ff кидает ошибку: _SyntaxError: fields are not currently supported_

Comment: хром как обычно